# Wrong target's image in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I have an app with a couple targets. Each target has its own xcassets catalog with a membership only for its target. I have an image with the same name in each catalog. When I add an ImageView in Interface Builder and specify the image, the image that shows up in Interface Builder is for the second target, regardless of which target I have selected. The correct image shows up when I run the project.

Is Interface Builder supposed to show the correct image depending on which target is selected?

Comment: It seems IB can't handle that. I tried both your case, and adding an image to IB with the storyboard belonging to different targets. I always got only one of them to show up. It seems it picks the first file available in the project file, regardless of targets.